# Capture groups recursively with regex between braces

Tags: regex, go

How to write a regex, that capture every group of these structures?

Tried this, but this just captures everything `(.*{.*}$)`

Want to have a group for each so that I can extract each one individually

```
NewRequest {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

```
NewResponse {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Complete structure:

```
NewRequest {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}

 NewResponse {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
 NewResponse {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
 NewResponse {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
 NewResponse {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just `(?s)NewRequest\s*\{.*?}` will do?

Comment: Updated the question so it's more clear what I was after. But your solution worked  with a bit of modification (\w*\s*\{.*?}) at least gives me 5 matches

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?s)\w+\s*\{.*?}
\w+\s*\{[^{}]*}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpyWrn/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)`  - a DOTALL modifier
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `}` - a `}` char.